# How to move toghether classic azure storage accounts to new resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I have 4 classic storage accounts in one subscription. They are related since they are created in the same affinity group.

When I try to move just one of them to another resource group they are moved together automatically ( there is a message in the portal : "Some related resources must remain in the same resource group and need to be moved with the selected resource [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources)" ) but then an error happens since there is a [limitation which says that classic resources can be moved only one by one.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#classic-deployment-limitations)

Here is the deadlock - I am forced by the portal to move them together but then I get an error because I have to move them one by one.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would open a support request in the portal...

Comment: Is this the only way? I do not min to open a support request either.

Comment: I don't know of another way and know this is a tricky scenario - so that might be the fastest (or only way) if it's possible.  You can also tweet @AzureSupport if you don't want to go the portal route.

Comment: Thank you @bmoore-msft. I tried tweeter but I can not put my question in 150 chars. I have sent a support request today.